# Solving $(n+1)X^{n+1}-(n-1)X^{n}-(n-1)X + n+1 =0$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve the following equation without any success:

$$(n+1)X^{n+1}-(n-1)X^{n}-(n-1)X + n+1 =0$$

I already tried to use the known formula:
$$x^{n+1} + \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} = \left( x + \frac{1}{x} \right)\left( x^{n} + \frac{1}{x^{n}} \right) - \left( x^{n-1} + \frac{1}{x^{n-1}} \right)$$

in:
$$(n+1)(X^{n+1} + X^{-(n+1)}) -(n-1)(X^{n} + X^{-n} + X+ X^{-1})+ 2(n+1) = 0$$
but I was not able to solve it. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $X=0$ is not a solution.  Thus, any solution satisfies $X=\exp(2\text{i}z)$ for some $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  Dividing the whole equation by $\exp\big((n+1)\text{i}z\big)$ to get
$$(n+1)\,\cos\big((n+1)z\big)=(n-1)\,\cos\big((n-1)z\big)\,.$$  This does not look very promising to me.

Comment: The equation above translates to $$\tan(z)\,\tan(nz)=\frac{1}{n}$$ by the way.  There are indeed $n+1$ solutions $z\in\left[0,\pi\right)$, but I do not know whether there is a closed form for them.